# Excel keyboard shortcut to deselect all

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I deselect all cells via keyboard without changing the active cell?

[image: deselect]

Comment: By pressing Escape?

Comment: @LPChip I tried pressing Escape. It didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shift + Backspace should do the trick(tried it on Excel 2016)

Comment: Where did you find the answer?

Comment: Just tried a few known shortcuts.

Comment: Known shortcuts: Click on empty space on the Desktop, hit `F1` and type `shortcut keys` +enter.

Comment: @Hannu I tried that and it [doesn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoZEa.png) this shortcut.

Comment: Also works on Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Double Click in a cell outside the selection area to de-select. Works in Office 2016 for Mac, using Version 15.33 (170409).

Note: Using the Escape key, Single Click and Shift+Delete *doesn't* deselect the area (for me using Office 2016 for Mac).

Comment: The question asks "without changing the active cell". Does this answer change the active cell?

Comment: This is an answer for a slightly different issue that I was looking for, so I'm glad it was listed so I could find it from google. If you click a cell, and Copy it (ctrl+c), it has the "marching ants" around it, even if you paste the data somewhere. In photoshop you can press ctrl+D to deselect those selections, but I don't see any "deselect" option in excel. Double-clicking a cell does eliminate the marching ants (Esc seems to as well though).